# PHP variable scope after multiple includes

Tags: php

Let's say I hava a page index.php and in it I execute:

```
require_once("file1.php");
echo $myVar;
```

in file1.php I have:

```
require_once("file2.php");
```

and in file2.php I have

```
$myVar = "test";
```

After executing this script, index.php can't get to $myVar and outputs undefined variable.
Any reason on that ?

Comment: Something else is affecting `$myVar` that you're not putting here. As it stands this problem can't be reproduced by your example.

Comment: there is no issue with this..

Comment: Works for me. There must be some other code that is relevant.

Comment: Are you including file1.php or file2.php in some other location first? `require_once` will only include the file if it has not already been included.

Comment: first try it guys, and then say it's something wrong with my code. I've been doing PHP for 5 years but it's the first time when I try 2-level include var scope...

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. It works. I did have to add `<?php`  to the top of each file. You have that, right?

Answer (score 2):

`require`/`include` act as if the contents of the file being included were literally cut/pasted into the place where the include directive is. Your variable will work, unless something else is trashing it between the include calls.

e.g.

core.php:

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar';
```

file1.php:

```
include('core.php');
$foo = 'baz';
```

file2.php

```
echo $foo; // undefined
include('core.php');
echo $foo; // outputs bar
include('file1.php');
echo $foo; // outputs baz
```

Comment: I know that's how it's supposed to be but it doesn't happen to me. I copy/paste your example and the same behaviour occurs. Where I include a variable from a second file it doesn't see it. Only on the first level include

Comment: @silver14_, try to replace `require_once` to `require` first of all. Look at comments to your question.